# Uiscrollbar is not scrolling

Tags: ipad, uiscrollview

I implemented a scrollbar for a landscape view:

```
//Add scrollview
    scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768)];
    scrollview.delegate = self;
    scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
    scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1024,2000);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
```

// adds subviews to scrollview

```
[self generateSubtaskElements:allObjects];
```

I tried to change the contentSize, but nothing happends. I cannot scoll the view.

Comment: scrollView should contains some view beyond its frame... then only it will scroll...

Comment: I added a lot of views like this if ([obj isKindOfClass:[Picture class]])
        {
            [scrollview addSubview:[self genereateImageView:x+250 :y :[(Picture*)obj path]]];
        }
        I also see the views but i cannot scroll the view

Comment: you should set the frame as greater than 768x1024

Comment: I also tried to set the frame greater    scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,2024,2068)]; But it is still the same problem

Comment: oh!.... add the imageView with frame of (800,1100, 400,300)... it will works